# Read only Excel Cells with values python win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have an Excel Document like the following

```
num value1 value2

1       A      100
2       B      
3       c      300
```

I want to iterate through `value2` for something with a value of over 200, and if it finds a value over 200, print `value1`. The big thing I'm having an issue with is telling it to stop the for loop once it reaches the end of the cells with text in it.

My loop would ideally be something like this:

```
while columnA is not empty:
     if value2 > 200:
           print (value1)
```

a few notes: I'm using win32com. `ColumnA` will never be blank within my data set. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Edit: I will not always have the same number of rows for each document. I need it to automatically stop. Sorry for not being clearer

Comment: Are you parsing xls, xlsx or a mixture of formats?

Comment: Would you consider using `pandas` library?

Comment: unfortunately I have to use the win32com library. I will be using only xlsx

Comment: Please post the actual"" code that you tr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using Excel's object library, specifically its [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or [Worksheet.Cells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx). Also, usually in Excel VBA, you search the worksheet to find the last row and then loop until you reach it:

**Excel worksheet**

[image: Excel Worksheet]

**Python COM Code** *(using try/except/finally to always release resources regardless of error or not)*

```
import win32com.client as win32

try:
    f = "myWorkbook.xlsx"
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f)
    ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    xlUp = -4162
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    for i in range(2,lastrow):
        # LOOP RANGE OBJ
        if ws.Range("C" + str(i)).Value is not None and ws.Range("C" + str(i)).Value > 200:
            print(ws.Range("B" + str(i)).Value)

        # LOOP CELLS OBJ
        if ws.Cells(i,3).Value is not None and ws.Cells(i,3).Value > 200:
            print(ws.Cells(i,2).Value)

    wb.Close(False)
    xl.Quit

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    ws = None
    wb = None
    xl = None
```

**Output**

```
c
c
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me significantly. The "lastrow" code was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Could anyone please explain the magic number     xlUp = -4162    ? Regardless, this helped me as well, +1.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar, see [Excel constants for *XlDirection* enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection).