# Excel COM API for reading the cell index using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com, office-automation

I am wiritng a Python script using Excel COM APIs. I wanted to search for a string in a excell cell ,once found I want to return the cell index(like A2 or B3).
what is the API I have to use for this..

Thx,
Jose

Comment: Please have a look at win32com library. It's pretty useful in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with open XML documents in Excel you may consider using the Open XML SDK for such tasks, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. You can try to search for any Python packages that provides the same functionality. See [Extracting Data from Excel Files](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/beyond_pcc/extracting_from_excel/) for more information.

Also you may consider automating Excel from Python. Read more about that in the [Read only Excel Cells with values python win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172580/read-only-excel-cells-with-values-python-win32com) thread which also provides a sample code for that.